# What is twisted's equivalent of tornado's IOLoop.add_callback?

Tags: python, twisted, tornado

I'm trying to adapt some tornado code to work with twisted.

Tornado's IOLoop has a function ([`add_callback`](http://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/ioloop.py#L302)) that will essentially call the function back in the next iteration of the loop.  As far as I can tell, twisted doesn't have a direct translation of this.  Is there any way to simulate this in twisted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`reactor.callLater(0, x)` or `reactor.callFromThread(x)`

Comment: Also known as <http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.1.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorTime.callLater.html> and <http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.1.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorThreads.callFromThread.html>.